# Windows Workflow Foundation equivalent of "lock"

Tags: c#, multithreading, workflow-foundation

I have a class that inherits from `SequentialWorkflowActivity`, which can be executed simultaneously in multiple threads, and I need to make sure that part of the activity is

- never interrupted
- never executed across multiple threads

How can I do this in a WWF custom activity?